# Quinoa Flour Substitute

Tags: substitutions, flour, quinoa

I don't have quinoa flour for a recipe that calls for 1/2 cup regular flour and 1/2 cup quinoa flour.  Gluten free is not necessary.

I have regular flour and whole wheat flour, which should I use for the 1/2 cup quinoa flour?

Comment: Welcome to the site! I would help you get a better answer if you told us what you are trying to make, and give us a recipe to work with. At the moment there's not enough information to answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend just using regular flour. Since this is not a GF recipe, the quinoa flour is likely added for nutritional reasons, including increasing the protein content. If that is not a concern of yours, just use regular flour. Using whole wheat flour would give you a different flavor profile.